# Check if an integer has any prime factors excluding some set

Tags: algorithms, prime-factorization

I'm looking for an algorithm that returns true if the set of prime factors of some number only contains values in some set $S$, and false otherwise

Example:

$S = \{2,5\}$

For the number $250$ the result is true, since the prime divisors are $2*5^3$
For the number $182$ the result is false, since the prime divisors are $2*7*13$

Since I don't need the actual divisors, I'm hoping there's a faster method than just factoring the number.

Comment: How large is $S$? If it is smallish, there is no faster way than to divide out all factors in $S$ and see whether the remaining factor is $1$ or not.

Comment: In my use case the set $S=\{2,5\}$

Comment: @ml0105: Darksonn asks if all prime divisors (of a given number) are a subset of $S$, not if $S$ is a subset of its prime divisors.  I agree with Daniel's suggestion to divide the given number by trial divisors in $S$.  I'm not convinced it is better to start with the larger trial divisors in $S$.  Note that although we ask about prime divisors belonging to $S$, nothing said guarantees that the numbers in $S$ are primes, though in the sample case $S=\{2,5\}$ both elements happen to be primes.

Comment: Note that the algorithm that tries to divide by the elements of $S$ only works if the elements of $S$ are prime together. In short, it works for prime factors (as it is asked) but would fail for dividers like $S=\{2, 10\}